# at undergraduate level or at the undergraduate level

Tags: articles

Should I say 'at undergraduate level' or 'at the undergraduate level'. I can find both online. To me, level is a countable noun, so I would prefer the latter one. But there are a lot sentences using the first one.

Comment: Both are fine, and there's little between them, even in register.

Comment: If there is any difference (and that's arguable as @EdwinAshworth says) it is that "the undergraduate level" is _slightly_ more likely to be used if you are speaking about the undergraduate level of a particular subject and "undergraduate level" slightly more likely to be used if you are referring to university education in general. For example "The physics department has the lab capacity to offer 15 hours of practical work per week to any student studying at the undergraduate level" as opposed to "Our university currently has 3000 people studying at undergraduate level".